# Enzyme testing onChangeHandler

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am passing `maxLength` as props for a component and want to truncate the value if it is longer than 10.

```
const onHandleChange = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    if (maxLength) {
      e.target.value = value.slice(0, maxLength);
    }
    onChange(e);
  };

  return (
    <div className='input' data-test='input'>
      <span className='input__title' data-test='input__title'>
        {title}
      </span>
      <input
        type='text'
        placeholder={placeholder}
        className='input__field'
        data-test='input__field'
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={onHandleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Test Example

```
test('pass maxLength to input', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<InputField maxLength={5} />);
  const inputField = wrapper.find(`[data-test="input__field"]`);;
  inputField.props().onChange({
    target: {
      value: '00000123',
    },
  });
  expect(inputField.props().value).toEqual('00000');
});
```

Result is **TypeError: onChange is not a function**

How to test this?

Comment: You truncated the error while it's the only way other users can understand what's wrong on your side. The error seems to refer to `onChange(e)`. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Test either the `onHandleChange()` (with the spy) itself or just test the expected output after simulating the input (forget about the implementation).